# VBScript - Displaying results of shell command in message-box using readline method within a function

Tags: function, vbscript, stdout, readline

The script below only displays the last line of the executed `cmd`. I can't figure out how to get it to capture and display all the `stdout` stream.

```
option explicit
dim wshell, result, box

set wshell = wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")

box = msgbox("Current ARP entries:" &vbcrlf& execstdout("cmd /c arp -a"))

function execstdout(cmd)
    set result = wshell.exec(cmd)
    do while result.stdout.atendofstream <> true
        execstdout = result.stdout.readLine
    loop
end function
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

***CORRECTED CODE***

```
option explicit
dim wshell, result, box

set wshell = wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")

box = msgbox("Current ARP entries:" & execstdout("cmd /c arp -a"))

function execstdout(cmd)
    set result = wshell.exec(cmd)
    do while result.stdout.atendofstream <> true
        execstdout = execstdout &vbcrlf& result.stdout.readLine
    loop
end function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit your the line `execstdout = result.stdout.readLine` to `execstdout = execstdout & vbcrlf & result.stdout.readLine`.

You always replace it with the next line. With this edit, you concatenate all lines in one String separated by linebreaks.

Comment: Wow! thanks for the fast reply... I see so each line read was replacing the next, instead of displaying in continuous form. That makes sense now. Thank you so much! :D - I can't mark this as the answer for another 6 mins! :/

Comment: No problem, glad to be of service! I think i can wait a few minutes :D